# Android custom zoom animation poor performance

Tags: android, animation, zooming

I have a bit specific problem, but hopefully someone will chime in and help.

I've written a custom zoom animation (posting runnables that change the target view to a handler between certain amount of time) but when i change the view's width and height it is as if I've performed a zoom around (0,0) of the view whereas I want to zoom around its center so I move the view by changing its margins accordingly. The thing is though that when the zoom iteration step is too small (i.e 0.01f and less) I have to change the margins of the view by something like 1px sometimes only in one of the directions which makes it look as if the animation is glitchy. I'm not sure of the exact reason but I've tried the following things:

1) I tried changing the margins by overriding onLayout() of my parent view which will be caled when setting the layoutParams upon zooming( I did this in order to avoid a second call to setLayoutParams() upon moving which actually now doesn't seem quite reasonable since setLayoutParams() just sets some flag which will be used later on).

2) I'm checking the new margins to set so that they are set only when there's a difference between the new and the old margins in both X and Y directions.

3)I tried using view.offsetLeftAndRight() view.offsetTopAndBottom() instead of changing the layout params in order to move the view, but it was again to no avail.

Any suggestions what will do the trick?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are choosing to post Runnables to a Handler instead of writing the animation in the XML?

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand you correctly you need to get Bitmap cache from view and draw it manually. In this case bitmap will be drawn without glitches (if Bitmap filtering is on).

You can do it in following steps:

1. get view cache - through View.getDrawingCache or by calling View.draw function
2. hide view
3. get current system time - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime (thanks to this you can calculate animation progress)
4. start posting runnables to invalidate your screen and check whether animation is ended
5. show view

Possibly it can be done via Android Animation class but I do not use it as it quite limited.